# Embed custom filter definition into jinja2 template?

Tags: python, templates, plugins, jinja2, customization

I'm writing some Jinja2 templates that I'd like to be able to reuse as painlessly as possible in tangentially related projects.  I have a set of custom convenience filters that I'd like the templates to "carry around" with them.  Is there a Jinja2 syntax for embedding filter definitions into a template itself?  Or a mechanism for embedding any kind of pure Python function into a Jinja2 template that can act on variables passed into the template?  I used to use mako, and there it was trivial to do this, but templating LaTeX in mako is painful because of the lack of custom syntax, so I had to make the switch.

Comment: do you want to define a filter file for your jinja ?

Answer (score 41):

There is **NO** way you can embed python directly into a Jinja2 Template, the way that I know of is to define in your application and add them to your Jinja2 environment instance. Like the following example taken from https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#writing-filters.

```
import jinja2

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/tmp')
env = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=loader)

def upperstring(input):
    """Custom filter"""
    return input.upper()

env.filters['upperstring'] = upperstring
temp = env.get_template('template.html')
temp.render(name="testing")
```

Here the Template I am using

```
{{ name | upperstring }}
```

Result is this

```
TESTING
```

Comment: Any idea on how to remove all the old filters?

Comment: If you mean removing all existing _default_ filters you could simple replace `env.filters` with an empty dictionary by doing `env.filters = {}`. Not sure however why would want to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant all the old "custom" filters. But I found that Jinja environment sets up the basic filters explicitly, so can't assign to empty dictionary.

Comment: @flazzarini How do you call upperstring and feed in the variable "input"? If I wanted a custom filter for boolean, how do I return the variable true/false that I pass in?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but If you would like to define a filter that would return a boolean type you could write something [here](https://repl.it/@FrankLazzarini/Custom-Jinja2-Filters) to transform any given strings into boolean values using a jinja2 filter.

Answer (score 20):

There is an easy way to add custom filters in `jinja2` template.
`FILTERS` is the dictionary containing all filters that we can use to render the template.
However, we can add more filters to it.

Here is a quick example to add new filters to it.

```
from jinja2 import Template
from jinja2.filters import FILTERS, environmentfilter


// Remove the decorator in the next line if using version 3.1.0 or higher, read below
@environmentfilter
def do_reverse_by_word(environment, value, attribute=None):
    """
    custom max calculation logic
    """
    if attribute:
        return [list(reversed(i.get(attribute).split())) for i in value]

    return list(reversed(value.split()))


FILTERS["reverse_by_word"] = do_reverse_by_word
print(Template("{{ name | reverse_by_word }}").render({"name": "Stack Overflow"}))
print(Template("{{ names | reverse_by_word(attribute='name') }}").render({"names": [{"name": "Stack Overflow"}, {"name": "Stack Exchange"}]}))
```

Outputs

```
['Overflow', 'Stack']
[['Overflow', 'Stack'], ['Exchange', 'Stack']]
```

please comment below in case you've more complex use cases. I'll be happy to answer all your queries.

**Update (tested with version `3.1.2`):** The decorator `environmentfilter` is no longer needed (and does not exist anymore). [Source](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/1544)

Comment: Hey @vikas you have'nt mentioned where to make this file/directory, and how we can access this file in our template.

Comment: Sorry but enviromentfilter is not found in jinja2.filters

Comment: This works without the environmentfilter decorator 