# TemplateSyntaxError: Expected token ',' got 'for'

Tags: python-3.x, pug, mixins

I want to display a block/call mixin only if some condition is true.
This is my code:

```
block details
                - var details = get_coverage_details()
                - var flag_display = all(value == [] for value in details.values())
                if not flag_display:
                    +details(details)
```

`get_coverage_details` is some python method in my code, which is getting me the dynamic content.

I am getting an error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'for'

The problem seems to be here `all(value == [] for value in details.values())`

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if not flag_display:
    +details(details)
```

to

```
if !flag_display
    +details(details)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was trying to use a Python method in a Jinja2 template that Jinja2 didn't support (in my case, `any()`, but I imagine it would also apply to `all()`).

See @flazzarini's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25450294/1960231).