# Include and exclude string output when rendering jinja2 template via filtering

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to construct a template to support configuration lines for a specific console platform.

The running-configuration is in this following format:

Example 1:

```
/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_mode=static
/settings/network_connections/ETH0/pv4_address=10.0.0.10
/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_bitmask=24 
/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_gateway=10.0.0.1
```

If you want to configure the following above lines, it's prepended by the word "set" like this:

Example 2:

```
set /settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_mode=static
set /settings/network_connections/ETH0/pv4_address=10.0.0.10
set /settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_bitmask=24 
set /settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_gateway=10.0.0.1
```

In my jinja2 template, I have something like this:

Example 3

```
{{ set| remediation }} /settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_mode=static
{{ set| remediation }} /settings/network_connections/ETH0/pv4_address=10.0.0.10
{{ set| remediation }} /settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_bitmask=24
{{ set| remediation }} /settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_gateway=10.0.0.1
```

I want to be able to render the template and be able to output what I have in Example 2 (with 'set') as well as the ability to output as Example 1 (without 'set') using a boolean variable (with_remediation). If True, include 'set' - else exclude 'set'. In Example 3, 'remediation' being a embedded custom filter.

```
import jinja2

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/tmp')
env = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=loader)

def remediation(input,with_remediation):
    """Custom filter"""
    if(with_remediation):
        return input
    else:
        return ""

env.filters['remediation'] = remediation
temp = env.get_template('template.jinja2')
temp.render(set="set")
```

But I'm unsure of how to pass the variable 'with_remediation' into the function remediate.

I have tried following the example [Embed custom filter definition into jinja2 template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449879/embed-custom-filter-definition-into-jinja2-template) provided in the answer, but not sure if it will help in what I'm trying to achieve.

Also, how can I code it so 'set' can be any 'string' I want it to be? Must I include every string I want to use in the `temp.render(set="set")` line? For example; `temp.render(set="set", delete="delete",rename="rename")` or if there a more efficient way of tackling this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get resolve it by doing this; output 'set' by setting with_remediation to True; exlude output 'set' by setting with_remediation to False:

```
import jinja2

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/tmp')
env = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=loader)

with_remediation = True

def remediation(input):
    """Custom filter"""
    if(with_remediation):
        return input
    else:
        return ''

env.filters['remediation'] = remediation
temp = env.get_template('template.jinja2')
temp.render(set='set')
```

Template:

```
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_mode=static
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/pv4_address=10.0.0.10
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_bitmask=24
{{ set | remediation }}/settings/network_connections/ETH0/ipv4_gateway=10.0.0.1
```